# XBee how to discover router or end device trough API?

Tags: angularjs, arduino, xbee

I'm working on a week-end project to setup a very basic angularjs web application con control xbees modules with an arduino attached to an Xbee Coordinator.

Long story short, is there any way to discover other modules that has join the network? I don't want to relay on the join notification because due to the boot time of the arduino board I'm not sure to catch all the notifications right in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are using a DigiMesh Network. Don't know how it is in the ZigBee one.

From the manual:

Issuing the ND command sends a broadcast network discovery command throughout the
network. All devices that receive the command will send a response that includes the device’s
addressing information, node identifier string (see NI command), and other relevant information.
This command is useful for generating a list of all module addresses in a network.

Comment: Thanks Lalo. Just add the frame for an "ND" command. It's a local AT command, to send directly to the local device:[0x7E,0x00,0x04,0x08,0x02,0x4E,0x44,0x63]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to know what the "other relevant information" is, I think I found it [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-900-Manual.pdf) on 
page 24.

For the API disregard the carriage returns at the end of each line. Most AT commands should be similar across different XBee radios, unless you change to DigiMesh or other protocols. I'm hoping the 900 MHz XBee has a similar setup.

```
Data Portion of Packet
MY 0x????              //in case of Digimesh 0xFFFE
SH 0x???? ????         //Serial High
SL 0x???? ????         //Serial Low
NI                     //Node Identifier 20 characters max. 
                       //if the string is 20 char long, there will be no NULL byte
Parent Network  0x???? //Parent's MY address. in case of Digimesh 0xFFFE
Device Type     0x??   //0 = Coord, 1 = Router, 2 = End Device
Profile ID      0x???? //
Manufacturer ID 0x??   //
```

Comment: Thanks Phlipi. However in one of my other questions I've figure out the complete response packet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677590/xbee-node-discovery-response/26684011?noredirect=1#comment42151233_26684011