# Xbee Node Discovery Response

Tags: arduino, xbee, arduino-ide

I'm trying to discover devices, from a coordinator, in my network. 
So I sent an ND command to the coordinator and I'm correctly receiving response from other Xbee.

The next step will be to store the information I've received in a web application, in oder to send commands and data.

However, what I'm still missing is some parts in the frame respose. So far I've mapped the frame like this:

```
1     7E                  start frame    
===== =================== MESSAGE LENGHT
2-3   0x00 0x19           -> 25
===== =================== PACKET TYPE
4     88                  -> response to a remote AT command
5     02                  frame ID
===== =================== AT COMMAND
6-7   0x4E 0x44           "ND"
8     00                  status byte (00 -> OK)

===== =================== MY - Remote Address
9-10  0x17 0x85
===== =================== SH - SERIAL NUMBER HIGH
11-14 0x00 0x13 0xA2 0x00
===== =================== SL - SERIAL NUMBER LOW    
15-18 0x40 0xB4 0x50 0x23
===== =================== SIGNAL     
19    20
= ======== NI - Node Identifier
20 00 
21 FF     
22 FE     
23 01   
24 00          
25 C1     
26 05
27 10     
28 1E     
===== ===== CHECKSUM (25th bytes from MESSAGE LENGHT)
29 19
```

So, where I can find in this response the address of the device ? 
My guess is in the NI part of the message but, I haven't find any example/information of how the data are organised.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone told me in the dig.com forum

```
NI<CR>                 (Variable length)
PARENT_NETWORK ADDRESS (2 Bytes)<CR>
DEVICE_TYPE            (1 Byte: 0=Coord, 1=Router, 2=End Device)
STATUS                 (1 Byte: Reserved)
PROFILE_ID             (2 Bytes)
MANUFACTURER_ID        (2 Bytes
```

So, loking to my frame response:

```
00   --- Node Identifier variable, (here 1 byte = 00 because no value is set up).
FFFE --- parent network address (2 bytes)
01   --- device type  
00   --- status
C105 --- profile id
101E --- manufacturing id
```

This, afaik, means that in this last part of the frame, no information about address of the device are given. Only information are the SL and SH.

Answer (score 0):

The 16-bit network address is what you've labeled "MY" (0x1785), and the 64-bit MAC address is the combination of SH/SL (00 13 A2 00 40 B4 50 23).

Comment: you are right @tomlogic do you know how to use the 16bit network address when sending a remote AT command? In every document I've red only 64bit are used.

Comment: You might be able to set the 64-bit IEEE address to all `0xFF` so the XBee module will use the 16-bit network address.  Make sure you're using the most recent firmware available.  **Ultimately though, it is more reliable (and not difficult) to use the 64-bit IEEE address and use `0xFFFE` as the network address.**  On some 802.15.4 networks, it's possible for the network address to change